# Magento URL rewrite Logic Needed

Tags: magento-1.9

Currently I am working on a Multi-vendor module in Magento.

**What I need to do:**

I need to include Vendor name in each URL.

Eg:

```
 - domain.com/vendor1/jewels.html 
 - domain.com/vendor2/jewels.html
```

And when user enter product URLs it should become

```
  - domain.com/vendor1/jewels/product1.html
  - domain.com/vendor2/jewels/product6.html
```

That means every URL will have the vendor string after `baseurl`.

***I need a functionality just like Magento uses with multi store were we can set store code in the URL and all frontend URL's will have that store code where we use Magento `getUrl` ***

Eg:

```
 - domain.com/en/jewels.html 
 - domain.com/fr/jewels.html
```

I Couldn't use this as client wants only one store to keep very low data replication by Magento and the vendor filtering logic is very simple which is already working. So I only have to include the vendor code string in URL like default Magento store code method.

**What I did So far:**

1. I made every URL to have vendor code at the end with normal way (by adding `GET` parameter).

   - domain.com/jewels.html?vendor=vendor1
   - domain.com/jewels.html?vendor=vendor2
2. With the help Apache vhosts config pointed every sub domain into same Magento added all vendors as sub domain so

   ```
   - vendor1.domain.com/jewels.html 
   - vendor2.domain.com/jewels.html
   ```

   Apparently both methods client doesn't want it and they are clear that they want only above method which I have no idea so far where to start. Any direction or any similar extension?

Your Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using category/subcategory/products configuration under Admin->Catalog->Manage Categories to configure a category each for vendor1 and vendor1 and add a subcategory called jewels into each category.

Followed by Admin->Catalog->Manage Products to add the products into each subcategory.

Comment: Please see my requirement once again - I cant use category or root category logic here.

Answer (score 1):

You can try extend "Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard" front router class to handle this by creating custom module since magento's order of routing dispatch is

```
Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Admin
Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard
Mage_Cms_Controller_Router
Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Default
```

So it will have effect only on frontend.